# Animated background with svg and css

Tags: css, svg

Does someone know how to do svg animations with CSS or small JS ?
Maybe there's a plugin to do that ?

https://wappalyzer.com/

Comment: either do it in SMIL or CSS animations

Comment: I don’t know SMIL, I’ll look at this ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- [MS-Edge doesn't support SMIL animations](https://caniuse.com/#search=smil).
- [MS Edge doesn't support animating svg's with css either](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8487752/).
- Google Chrome was planning to depricate SMIL (because you can use css animations instead), but they decided not to for now (but they probably will in the future)

So your remaining options are: javascript or give microsoft the finger and decide not to support their browser and use css animations (preferably) or SMIL.

Hope it helps and gives you some insight in what (not to) do. To answer in more detail I really need to know what you are trying to animate. That said, you should find plenty of examples/tutorials when you google for it. If you want to find something specific you can always check the [Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) 1.1 (Second Edition) Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html).

Comment: Thanks :) But I don't care about MS-Edge :) Actually I never used SVG, and it would be very nice if I know how to do the effect in my link !

Comment: It seems very straightforward. Just animate the coordinates of the dots and lines to wherever you want. Can you show some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Very straightforward ?! I think it's really hard ^^ I don't begin to code, actually I know how to begin ..

Comment: First make an unanimated version (with just circle and line elements). Then you animate the x and y coordinates of the circles and lines, so they move around.